# How do old CPUs execute the new ENDBR64 and ENDBR32 instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, control-flow

At some point, Intel will begin shipping CPUs that support CET(**C**ontrol-flow **E**nforcement **T**echnology), which adds two instructions `ENDBR64` and `ENDBR32`.

These two will be encoded as

```
F3 0F 1E FA   for ENDBR64 and 
F3 0F 1E FB   for ENDBR32 respectively.
```

How will these be executed on older x86 CPUs?
For instance, a Core i5 or even the vintage Pentium II?

Update:

```
F3 0F = prefix indicating newer instructions
1E = ENDBR
FA = ENDBR64
```

Comment: The instruction set reference lists them as "reserved - NOP". However It's unclear to me whether the cpu would know to fetch the last byte too.

Comment: @Jester They are documented to have a modr/m byte, so it should be fine.

Comment: It's not clear to me that it is the case. `0F 1F` is listed as `NOP /0 Ev` so that does have modrm. But `0F 1E` is just `NOP`.

Comment: If I had an older Pentium CPU I would try these on it, but I don't. Does anyone here by chance have one?

Comment: Older Intel documentation (June 2014) has that blank in the opcode map, which is "reserved and must not be used."  Newer docs (January 2019) has it listed as "Reserved - NOP" and does not list the ENDBR instructions.  So it might be a NOP on newer CPUs and something else (Illegal instruction?  Nop?) on older ones.  Safest would be to check the CPUID flags to check for support before running them.

Comment: Your update to your question is sub-optimal. Section 3.1.1.2 of the Intel Manual states that the byte sequence F3.0F can have several meanings.

Comment: @zx485 I cannot find a manual that is earlier than 2011 or so.

Answer (score 11):

Older GDB decodes `F3 0F 1E FA  ENDBR64` as `repz nop edx`.

Single-stepping it on a Core 2 (Merom) in 64-bit mode produces no change in architectural state, and no faults / exceptions.  (Tested in GDB 7.10 on an old Ubuntu 15.10 install).

---

According to https://gist.github.com/Quasilyte/b60c94b9cb608d5b1a359d54f1be8aca,
 **`0f 1e /r` is a 2-byte opcode that takes a ModRM**, `NOP r/m32, r32`, the same as the standard multi-byte [`0f 1f` NOP that Intel documents](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/nop).

It says it was added with Pentium Pro, so any PII / PIII or later would be fine.

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/197#issuecomment-472906147 says AMD documents these extra NOP opcodes; Intel lists them as "reserved".

**`rep` prefixes are usually silently ignored for opcodes they don't apply to.**  This gives Intel/AMD the flexibility to use REP as part of the mandatory prefixes for future instructions to create encodings that won't fault on old CPUs.

---

**CPUs older than PPro, e.g. original Pentium, would probably fault on it.**  Just like for `0f 1f` long NOP.

---

BTW, your attempt at decoding it makes no sense.  `0f` is the "escape" byte for 2-byte opcodes, so `1e  push ds` is unrelated to how this will decode.  That's how `1e` decodes by itself, without a `0f` escape byte.  (Except in 64-bit mode where it's invalid.)

Comment: More specifically, `endbr64` is within what is labeled "HINT_NOP" space.  These are redundant encodings of the official multi-byte NOP instruction.  HINT_NOP is explicitly reserved space for future instructions, but with the proviso that current processors will interpret them as NOP.  This way, some future instructions like `endbr64` can be added in this space if ignoring the opcode is a safe action to do on older processors.  A similar trick was done for `pause` before HINT_NOP was invented. (`pause` is encoded as if `repz nop`.)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a problem with the `ENDBR32` instruction myself recently. VirtualBox version `6.0.14_Ubuntu r132055` incorrectly decodes `ENDBR32` as a sequence of an illegal opcode and `STI`. This would produce all sorts of errors as I need interrupts disabled. The only solution I came up with is to invoke GCC with `-fcf-protection=branch` and `-mmanual-endbr` options enabled.

[VirtualBox debug console on the top, Objdump on the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xA52.png)

Comment: Was this fixed? Wow.